# Match associative array key with string or ip address

Tags: bash

I'm trying to match an associative array key with a string or ip address. I followed ur script but I get empty output.

```bsh
declare -A assArray1=( [156.119.57.30]="156.119.57.31" [156.119.57.10]="156.119.57.11" [156.119.57.21]="156.119.57.22" )
keys=()

IPADDR=$(ip addr show |grep 'eth0'|grep -v 127.0.0.1 |awk '{print $2}'| cut -d/ -f1 | cut -d':' -f2)
#Example IPADDR=156.119.57.10
for i in "${!assArray1[@]}";do
 if [[ ${assArray1[$i]} == "$IPADDR" ]]; then
   keys+=( "$i" )
 fi
done

echo ${keys[@]} #output should be  156.119.57.10
```

Comment: Welcome, besides other problems that may occur, did you check the value of `IPADDR`? [edit] the question adding it.

Comment: i do checked IPADDR value of the variable which ip address of server 156.119.57.10

Answer (score 0):

The `i` in the for loop [is the *index* of the array's elements](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

> **${!name[@]}**
> **${!name[*]}**
>
> If name is an array variable, expands to the list of array indices (keys) assigned in name. If name is not an array, expands to 0 if name is set and null otherwise. When ‘@’ is used and the expansion appears within double quotes, each key expands to a separate word.

In your case:

```
[156.119.57.30]="156.119.57.31"
```

You are comparig the *value* instead, you can see it better printing the variables

```bsh
$ for i in "${!assArray1[@]}"; do
    echo "${assArray1[$i]}"
  done
156.119.57.11
156.119.57.31
156.119.57.22
```

So to compare the keys:

```bsh
$ for i in "${!assArray1[@]}"; do
    if [[ "$i" = "$IPADDR" ]]; then
      keys+=( "$i" )
    fi
  done
$ echo "${keys[@]}"
156.119.57.10
```

Comment: i tried with $i = $IPADDR still no results

Comment: IPADDR=$(ip addr show |grep 'eth0'|grep -v 127.0.0.1 |awk '{print $2}'| cut -d/ -f1 | cut -d':' -f2)

#echo $IPADDR

declare -A assArray1=( [156.119.57.30]="156.119.57.31" [156.119.57.10]="156.119.57.11" [156.119.57.21]="156.119.57.22" )

keys=()

for i in "${!assArray1[@]}";do

 echo "$i"

 if [[ "$i" = "$IPADDR" ]]; then

   keys+=( "$i" )

 fi

done

echo "${keys[@]}"

Comment: the same logic work if i enter string value directly but not through variable as input with  below script
if [ ${assArray1["$IPADDR"]+_} ]; then echo "Found"; else echo "Not found"; fi # Not working
if [ ${assArray1["156.119.57.10"]+_} ]; then echo "Found"; else echo "Not found"; fi # working

Comment: any idea as why i am getting empty output. please advise

Comment: @Sathish [edit] the question showing a real example of the output of `ip addr show |grep 'eth0'|grep -v 127.0.0.1 |awk '{print $2}'| cut -d/ -f1 | cut -d':' -f2`, the *direct* output, no assigned to a variable.

Comment: @Sathish better yet, just show the output of `ip addr show |grep 'eth0'|grep -v 127.0.0.1`.

Comment: [admin@cmhbb16db ~]$ ip addr show |grep 'eth0'|grep -v 127.0.0.1 |awk '{print $2}'| cut -d/ -f1 | cut -d':' -f2

156.119.57.10
[admin@cmhbb16db ~]$

Comment: this command will be run each server to change their respective ip address to a new ip address from the array matching list